# Cloudflare и прием платежей

Tags: cloudflare

После смены dns на cloudflare, перестал работать прием платежей от пользователей. Каким способом можно убрать ограничения с ссылки приема платежей, кроме как отключить проксирование всего сайта?

Comment: Пробовал добавить в whitelist ip системы оплаты, и создал правило отключения защиты на путь оплаты, не помогло

Answer (score 1):

От cloudflare требовался чисто только cdn, проблему решил, добавив subdomain с отключенным проксированием. На основном проксирование и cdn включены.